# Is Hisoka basically immortal?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

In "Hisoka vs Chrollo", Hisoka lost the challenge, his legs and hands, and also his life as well. But after a moment, he came back alive and with his other body parts.(regenerate with rubber body)

So my question are:

1. Does other Nen user have this ability too? (I mean get killed and then retrieved by Nen just like Hisoka. )

Comment: Wasn't how he did that explained or shown in the manga? AFAIK, it was shown. I forgot some parts on how but it was definitely explained in the manga.

Comment: @W.Are the relevant chapter should be [chapter 357](https://hunterxhunter.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_357)

Comment: @AkiTanaka Is it only Hisoka be able to use that skill?

Comment: If you're referring to his abilities (Bungee Gum and Texture Surprise), then yes, he is the only one able to do that, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those who have been following the manga into the Dark Continent ark will already know the answer:in **Chapter 373**, Prince Camilla's nen ability allows her to be revived after death in return for the life of the the attacker.

A related and slightly more interesting discussion might be whether this was plausible given the information we had on nen pre-Camilla. The idea of nen getting stronger after death is introduced in **Chapter 120**, in the Yorknew Arc. From the wiki

> The most common reason for this phenomenon to occur is the ability of
>   the dying user while harboring a strong grudge will cause their Nen to
>   seek out the object of their hatred and cling to it

We've been told that post-mortem nen is *stronger* that usual nen, but that doesn't necessarily mean it can do all the sophisticated things that a nen-user can manage when alive with a functioning brain. However, there's strong evidence to suggest that post-mortem nen can carry out everything the nen-user could pre-program when alive.

On a fairly basic level, the Phantom Troupe were worried about Kurapika's nen going to Chrollo and potentially killing him. There are two ways I can envisage this happening. Firstly, there's also a risk from the nen itself; we learn in **Chapter 48** that just sending nen into someone not protected by their own nen is enough to break them into bits. Secondly, the chain around his heart could be activated by the post-mortem nen. However this would mean Kurapika's nen activated without Chrollo necessarily breaking the rules, so the post-mortem nen is not following the original rules (we see in **Chapter 352** that this is possible but with a bit of a complicated mess with mixing abilities). So we see Kurapika's hypothetical post-mortem nen doing two things 1) moving to a different location or 2) activating an already implemented ability.

Of these two, its mainly the latter that we see later. In **Chapter 307** Pitou's post-mortem nen ability moves Pitou's corpse in order to kill Gon. Note that Pitou had already implemented his ability onto himself and Pitou's ability was already able to move corpses. Now to **Chapter 356/357**, Hisoka is able to *program* his post-mortem nen to beat his heart and lungs after death. It's debatable whether he already had the ability to program his bungee gums to activate at certain times without his input, but it's certainly plausible. In either case, it doesn't hurt our argument that *post-mortem nen can do everything it's original user could program it to do*.

So we've seen that post-mortem nen can be programmed (and we've seen pretty sophisticated programming going into nen abilities - Bomber for example). Now nen can do pretty much anything plausible in universe for the right price. So there are two questions remaining: 1) is coming back to life allowed in the world of HxH? 2) what would the price be?

Just to emphasise that this isn't stupidly obvious from our previous discussion; whether Hisoka actually died in the sense that his brain stopped functioning completely is arguably ambiguous; one can go a [fair amount of time](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2013/11/long-persons-heart-stopped-wouldnt-try-revive/) with your heart stopped before you die and as this is HxH world, we can assume everyone is a little superhuman.

I think what appears to be an unrelated fact is relevant here: the Chimera ants and the memories of their 'previous life'. Scientifically, I'm fairly certain there is no way that a mushed up mix of brain and genes can retain lifetimes of memories (but I'm no expert here) and Togashi even refers to the soul in **Chapter 337** to explain this:

> The soul is probably small, but it has the energy to reincarnate itself

So reincarnation with memories is possible in HxH canon. It doesn't take a big leap to say that revivification is possible, as long as the body is intact, as required.

To summarise, post-mortem nen can do what you program it to, nen can do pretty much anything that is allowed in universe and revivification is plausible. As for the price - who knows - anything goes really when you ask what balances out with bringing somebody back to life, from 'life is priceless' (e.g. FMA) to 'life for a life'. But revivification nen abilities are cool, bring an interesting dimension to nen fights, and HxH is written by Togashi, so perhaps a Prince Camilla type nen ability is to be expected.